# CockroachDB 2-phase commits with or without blocking?

Tags: cockroachdb

Two-phase commits are supposed to suffer from blocking problems. Is that the case with CockroachDB, and if not, how is it avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachDB has a long blog post on how it uses 2-phase commit without locking here: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/how-cockroachdb-distributes-atomic-transactions/

The part that deals most with the prevention of locking is its use of "write intents" (**Stage: Write Intents** is the heading in the blog post).

Comment: It's not that clear how it behaves on concurrent transactions.

Comment: @aholbreich, Arjun Narayan just added a more detailed answer. Does it help?

Comment: it helps a bit. However i would like to compare characteristics of MVCC to the characteristics 2p somehow.

Answer (score 5):

**Summary**: 2-phase commits are blocking, so it is important to keep the thing that is being 2-phase committed as "small" as possible, so that the set of all actions that are blocked is minimal. CockroachDB does this using MVCC with *intents*, 2-phase committing only on a single intent. Because CockroachDB provides *serializable* transactions, it reorders transaction timestamps to minimize blocking only to where absolutely necessary.

#### Longer answer

[2-phase commits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol#Basic_algorithm) are blocking after the first phase, while all participants wait for a reply from the *coordinator* as to whether the second phase is to be committed or aborted. During this time period, participants that have already sent a "Yes" vote cannot unilaterally revoke their vote, but also cannot treat it as committed (as the coordinator might get back with an abort). So they are forced to block all subsequent actions that need to concretely know what the state of this transaction is. The key in the above sentence is in the "**need**": it is on us to design our system to reduce that set to the bare minimum. CockroachDB uses *write intents* and *[MVCC]* to minimize these dependencies.

Consider a naïve implementation of a distributed (multi-key) transactional key-value store: I wish to transactionally commit some write transaction `t1`. `t1` spans many keys across many machines, but of particular concern is that it writes `k1 = v2`. `k1` is on machine `m1` (let's say `k1=v1` was the previous value).

Since `t1` spans many keys on many machines, all of them are involved in a 2-phase commit transaction. Once that 2-phase transaction is begun, we have to note that we have an intent to write `k1=v2`, and the status of the transaction is unknown (the transaction may abort, because one of the *other* writes cannot proceed).

Now if some other transaction `t2` comes along which wants to read the value of `k1`, we simply cannot give that transaction an authoritative answer, until we know the final result of the 2-phase commit. `t2` is blocked.

But, we (and CockroachDB) can do better. We can keep *multiple versions* of values for each key, and have a *concurrency control* mechanism to keep all of these versions in order. Namely, we can assign our transactions *timestamps*, and have our writes look (loosely) as follows:

```
`k1 = v1 committed at time=1`
`k1 = v2 at time=110 INTENT (pending transaction t1)`
```

Now, when `t2` comes along, it has an option: it can choose to do the read at `time<=109`, which would not be blocked on `t1`. Of course, some transactions cannot do this (if say, they also are distributed, and there's a different component that simply requires a higher timestamp). Those transactions will be blocked. But in practice, this frees up the database to assign timestamps such that many types of transactions can proceed.

As the other answer says, Cockroach Labs has a post about CockroachDB's use of MVCC [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/how-cockroachdb-distributes-atomic-transactions/), which explains some further details as well.